# Can a character cast a ritual spell higher than their level?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rituals

I've seen in Warlocks that their max level spells don't reach 9th level, even though their spell list goes into 9th level spells. In the meantime, an Eldrich Knight can use the wizard spell list, but only up to level 4 spells. Obviously there are ritual spells above the class' limit, but are they able to be cast?

If a character picks up the ritual caster feat, are they limited by their class on how high they can cast a ritual spell? This is assuming that the character has access to the spell, and is able to put it into their ritual book.

Comment: Side note: warlocks can cast spells over level 5, but it is not a part of their pact magic feature, but another called mystic arcanum.

Comment: You might want to check the Mystic Arcanum class feature for the warlock to see why this doesn't apply to them then revise your question.

Comment: Good to know, that helps my understanding with Warlocks. Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The ritual caster feat can even be taken by characters that have no class able to cast a spell. Thus the level of spells they can copy into their book and consequently cast as a ritual scales with their (overall) character level:

> The spell must be on the spell list for the class you chose, **the
>   spell's level can be no higher than half your level** (rounded up),
>   and it must have the ritual tag. (PHB 169, emphasis mine)

The fact that you *have* the spellcasting or pact magic class feature does not affect the abilities gained from the feat. So yes, even if you can only cast 2nd level spells as a sorcerer3/barbarian2, you could copy and cast a 3rd level ritual spell with the feat.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the quoted sentence is part of a paragraph that seems to be describing which spells can be *copied into* the book; it does not provide any guidance about what levels of spells can be ritualistically *cast* by characters of a certain level. That said, I've been unable to find any guidance in the RAW about the *casting* half of the equation. So the rule of thumb that Szega seems to be applying — if you can copy it you can cast it — seems reasonable. But I don't think that it's actually stated, as such.

Answer (score 6):

The feat itself specifies:

> The spell's level can be no higher than half your level (rounded up), and it must have the ritual tag.